# How do I find P(X+Y<1/2)

Tags: probability

I am trying to calculate $P(X+Y \leq \frac{1}{2})$.

I know that $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = 8xy \ \, 0<y<x<1$ and $f_X(x) = 4x^3 \ , 0 < x < 1$ and $f_Y(y) = 4(y-y^3) \ , 0 < y < 1$ which means that X and Y are not independent.

How do I proceed? I know the answer is 1/96 and I have tried to calculate $\int_0^{1/2} \int_0^x 4x^3 + 4(y-y^3)dydx$ but that is not correct and I have tried all possible boundaries.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The probability is $\int_0^{1/4} \int_0^{x} 8xy dy dx+\int_{1/4}^{1/2} \int_0^{\frac 1 2-x} 8xy dy dx$. There is no reason to write down $f_X$ and $f_Y$. Directly compute the probability using the joint density.

Comment: I know that the joint PDF is $f_{X,Y} = 8xy$ which means that X and Y is not independent as $f_{X,Y} \neq f_X(x)f_Y(y)$. So you say there is no answer? This is an earlier exam question from my course.

Comment: If you know the joint density you should add that to your question. You have  only specified $f_X$ and $f_Y$. These two densities do not determine $P(X+Y<\frac 1 2)$. @MathiasNissen

Comment: I'm sorry. But if I calculate $\int_0^{1/2} \int_0^{1/2-x} 8xy dy dx$ I get 1/48 and not 1/96?

Comment: @MathiasNissen You should either modify the question giving the joint density or delete it . The question does not make sense as it is.

Comment: I have modified the question.

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- $P(X+Y<\frac12)=\mathbb Eg(X,Y)$ where $g:\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ is the function that takes value $1$ if $x+y<\frac12$ and takes value $0$ otherwise.
- $\mathbb Eg(X,Y)=\int g(x,y)f_{X,Y}(x,y)dxdy$